# 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat - Tuesday 22:00 UTC / 5pm EST

Tags: discussion, election

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2012 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat Digest](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest)

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Tuesday the 31st at 22:00 UTC / 5:00pm EST

**[view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=1&day=31&year=2012&hour=22&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)**

**[register here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/251/programmers-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)**

---

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the primary phase.  This means that I am looking at the 30th-1st. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=programmers.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: I added my availability, and will try my best to participate.

Comment: I cannot make that time. Is it possible to answer the questions 
post-scheduled-time?

Comment: @Jae yes of course.  Just answer questions in the room afterwards and it'll be included in the digest.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff: Thank You! Is there any specific way to go about doing this?

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff: Such as, do I have to ping somebody to become a part of the digest?

Comment: @All: I apologize but I will not be able to attend as well.  I will jump onto the room a little later to answer questions.  Thank you for inviting me.